# Cannot set UIScrollView to be scroll in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I need to add a `UIScrollView` in a `UITableView`, but it does not work.

I have set `scrollEnabled`, `alwaysBounceVertical`, `delaysContentTouches`, `canCancelContentTouches`, but still same.

```
var scrolling: UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.width,50))
scrolling.userInteractionEnabled = true

var style1: NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style1.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
style1.alignment = .Center
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(newsValue_withPrintintFormat[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)])
var ns_range1:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0,attributedString.length)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style1, range: ns_range1)


var content = UILabel( frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 0,width: self.view.frame.width-10 ,height: size.height) )
content.attributedText = attributedString
content.numberOfLines = 0
content.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
content.sizeToFit()
scrolling.contentSize = size

scrolling.addSubview(content)
scrolling.sizeToFit()
scrolling.delegate = self
scrolling.scrollEnabled = true
scrolling.alwaysBounceVertical = true
scrolling.delaysContentTouches = true
scrolling.canCancelContentTouches = false
cell!.contentView.addSubview(scrolling)
cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: it will clash of both tableview's scrollview and your scrollview....

Comment: How can I reconigze the scrollview and tableview when user scroll?

Comment: UItableview has there own delegate Methods like scrollview had if you want to use both in same than try to implement both's method of scrollview did scroll.

Comment: it cannot implement  both's method of scrollview did scroll which cause the error "Invalid redeclaration of 'scrollViewDidScroll'"

Comment: I have fixed it which is the content size of scrollview is 0 and the `cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled` should be true. thank you very much for your helping.

Comment: ok....welcome..keep coding

Comment: Are you trying to add it to a UITableViewCell or to the UITableView's header or footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 places that need to change or add which are `scrolling.contentSize = size` and `cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = true`